# $L^{2}$ inner product inequality.

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a random variable which takes values on $L^{2}$ space, $L^{2}(K)$ (the set of $L^{2}$ functions $f:K\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $K$ a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^{p}$). Let $f_{0}\in L^{2}(K)$ be a function such that 
\begin{equation}\nonumber
\text{E}[\|X - f_{0}\|_{L^{2}}^{2}] = \inf_{g\in L^{2}(K)}\text{E}[\|X - g\|_{L^{2}}^{2}].
\end{equation}
This is the same to say that
\begin{equation}\nonumber
\text{E}[\langle X - f_{0},X - f_{0}\rangle_{L^{2}}] = \inf_{g\in L^{2}(K)}\text{E}[\langle X - g,X - g\rangle_{L^{2}}].
\end{equation}
We also have that
\begin{equation}\nonumber
\text{E}[|X(k) - f_{0}(k)|] = \inf_{g\in L^{2}(K)}\text{E}[|X(k) - g(k)|],
\end{equation}
for all $k\in K$. My question is whether or not it is satisfied the following inequality
\begin{equation}\nonumber
\text{E}[\langle X - f_{0}, X - g\rangle_{L^{2}}]\leq 2\cdot\text{E}[\langle X - g, X - g\rangle_{L^{2}}],
\end{equation}
for all $g\in L^{2}(K)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz in $L^2(K)$, we have
$$
|\langle X-f_0, X-g\rangle| \leq \sqrt{\langle X- f_0, X-f_0\rangle}\sqrt{\langle X- g, X-g\rangle},
$$
which is a product of two real-valued random variables on our background space (call it $\Omega$). Thus, applying Cauchy-Schwarz to $L^2(\Omega)$, we get
$$
|\mathbb{E}\langle X-f_0, X-g\rangle|\leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}\langle X- f_0, X-f_0\rangle}\sqrt{\mathbb{E}\langle X- g, X-g\rangle}\leq \mathbb{E} \langle X-g,X-g\rangle,
$$
by assumption, so it doesn't seem to me that you even need the factor $2$?

Comment: I don't see how do you get the second inequality and where do you use the first inequality.

Comment: $|\mathbb{E}\langle X-f_0,X-g\rangle|\leq \mathbb{E}|\langle X-f_0,X-g\rangle| \leq \mathbb{E} \sqrt{\langle X-f_0,X-f_0 \rangle} \sqrt{\langle X-g,X-g \rangle}=\langle\sqrt{\langle X-f_0,X-f_0 \rangle},\sqrt{\langle X-g,X-g \rangle}\rangle_{L^2(\Omega)} $.

Comment: Now apply Cauchy-Schwarz to the right-hand side.

Comment: I see, it is all clear. My final question is why can you apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to $L^{2}(\Omega)$? I mean, w i have to check that $\langle\cdot ,\cdot\rangle_{L^{2}(\Omega)}$ is a inner product, right?.

Comment: But that's always the case? All $L^2$-spaces are Hilbert spaces (and conversely, at least assuming choice, every Hilbert space is isometrically isomorphic to some $L^2$-space).

Comment: That's true. Thank you for your explanation.